# Long formulas in VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have a lenghty formula which if I manually add this into a cell it works, however when i try to input the same formula using VBA R1C1 it errors out. What this formula does is to textjoin values in column D, for rows where column A contains the same value. Please find below code.

Range("O2").Formula2R1C1 = "=IF($A1<>$A2,IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(",",0,$D2:INDEX($D2:$D$11,MATCH(1,--($A2:$A$11<>$A2),0)-1)),TEXTJOIN(",",0,$D2:$D$11)),O1)"

I tried amending it to the below code but it didnt work as well.
Error msg: Run-time error '1004': Application-definted or object-defined error

Range("O2").Formula2R1C1 = "=IF($A1<>$A2,IFERROR(TEXTJOIN("","",0,$D2:INDEX($D2:$D$11,MATCH(1,--($A2:$A$11<>$A2),0)-1)),TEXTJOIN("""","""",0,$D2:$D$11)),O1)"

Would appreciate some advise on this!

Comment: First, you are using A1 formula style and are trying to pass it as a R1C1 formula. Second while you need to double the double-quotes `"`->`""` when used in formulas, as you did in the first part of your correction, you don't need to quadruple them `"`-x-`""""` like you did in the end.

Comment: try `Range("O2").Formula2 = "=IF($A1<>$A2,IFERROR(TEXTJOIN("","",0,$D2:INDEX($D2:$D$11,MATCH(1,--($A2:$A$11<>$A2),0)-1)),TEXTJOIN("","",0,$D2:$D$11)),O1)"`

Comment: Not sure about the `...$D2:INDEX(...` part, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Range("O2").Formula2R1C1="=IF(R[-1]C1<>RC1,IFERROR(TEXTJOIN("","",0,RC4:INDEX(RC4:R11C4,MATCH(1,--(RC1:R11C1<>RC1),0)-1)),TEXTJOIN("","",0,RC4:R11C4)),R[-1]C)"
```

(once you have a working A1-style formula then you can call the [ConvertFormula](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.convertformula) method to yield the equivalent R1C1-style version)